# Unity creating arrays of my already made Editor/Property Drawer that has arrays in it

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I feel I am very close but for the life of me I cannot figure this out as I keep getting funky results.  In the image below I am wanting to make multiple of these but I just cant figure it out:

[image]

As you can see that I can see in the image above I would like there to be another "Size" which I can set a number and multiple of what you see in the red box would show up.

At the moment I have a Camera_Positioning script with an Editor, a [System.Serializable] script that hold the variables and a Drawer that goes with it.

I have tried making a script that would make an array of Camera_Positioning and I also attempted something along the lines of 2D arrays but I doesn't work or I am doing something wrong.  Anyone have any ideas on how to make an array of the red boxes I have?

EDIT : Here is the code that I have currently :

My Camera_Positioning and Camera_Positioning_Editor script.  The Camera_Positioning is what I attach to my GameObject.

```
public class Camera_Positioning : MonoBehaviour {

    public CamPosLookArray[] PosLook;

}


[CanEditMultipleObjects]
[CustomEditor(typeof(Camera_Positioning))]
public class Camera_Positioning_Editor : Editor {

SerializedProperty posLook;


void OnEnable()
{
    // Setup the SerializedProperties.
    posLook = serializedObject.FindProperty("PosLook");
}

public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    // Set the indentLevel to 0 as default (no indent).
    EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;
    // Update
    serializedObject.Update();

    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(posLook.FindPropertyRelative("Array.size"));

    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Camera Position", EditorStyles.boldLabel, GUILayout.Width(Screen.width / 2.8f));
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Camera Look", EditorStyles.boldLabel, GUILayout.Width(Screen.width / 2.8f));
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Story", EditorStyles.boldLabel, GUILayout.Width(75f));
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

    for (int i = 0; i < posLook.arraySize; i++)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(posLook.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i), GUIContent.none);
    }

    // Apply.
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
}
```

My CamPosLookArray script:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class CamPosLookArray  {

public CameraPos_CameraLook[] PosLookArray;
}
```

My CameraPos_CameraLook and CameraPos_CameraLook_Editor script:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class CameraPos_CameraLook {

    public Transform CameraPosition;
    public Transform CameraLook;
    public int CameraStory;
}


[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(CameraPos_CameraLook))]
public class CameraPos_CameraLook_Drawer : PropertyDrawer {

// Draw the property inside the given rect
public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
{
    // Using BeginProperty / EndProperty on the parent property means that
    // prefab override logic works on the entire property.
    EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

    // Draw label
    position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);

    // Don't make child fields be indented
    var indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
    EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;

    // Calculate rects
    Rect camPos = new Rect(position.x, position.y, Screen.width / 3f, position.height);
    Rect camLook = new Rect(position.x + Screen.width / 2.75f, position.y, Screen.width / 3f, position.height);
    Rect camStory = new Rect(position.x + (2.2f *Screen.width) / 3f, position.y, 75f, position.height);

    // Draw fields - passs GUIContent.none to each so they are drawn without labels
    EditorGUI.PropertyField(camPos, property.FindPropertyRelative("CameraPosition"), GUIContent.none);
    EditorGUI.PropertyField(camLook, property.FindPropertyRelative("CameraLook"), GUIContent.none);
    EditorGUI.PropertyField(camStory, property.FindPropertyRelative("CameraStory"), GUIContent.none);

    // Set indent back to what it was
    EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;

    EditorGUI.EndProperty();
}
```

}

When I have all that I get :

[image]

What I am trying to achieve in the picture above is everywhere you see a triangle (2 of them) should be what is in the first picture at the top in the red box.

Comment: Edited with my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making a few tweaks to the `Camera_Positioning_Editor` script I managed to get the inspector to look like this:

[image: Inspector]

This is `OnInspectorGUI` method of the `Camera_Positioning_Editor` script:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;
    serializedObject.Update();

    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(posLook
                   .FindPropertyRelative("Array.size"));

    for(int i = 0; i < posLook.arraySize; i++)
    {
        SerializedProperty item = posLook.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
        SerializedProperty posLookArrayProperty = 
            item.FindPropertyRelative("PosLookArray");

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(
            posLookArrayProperty.FindPropertyRelative("Array.size"));

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Camera Position", 
            EditorStyles.boldLabel, GUILayout.Width(Screen.width / 2.8f));
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Camera Look", 
            EditorStyles.boldLabel, GUILayout.Width(Screen.width / 2.8f));
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Story", 
            EditorStyles.boldLabel, GUILayout.Width(75f));
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        for(int j = 0; j < posLookArrayProperty.arraySize; j++)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(
                posLookArrayProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(j), GUIContent.none);
        }
    }

    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

In this example the top `Size` property is the size of the array within the `Camera_Positioning` component. Each subsequent `Size` is for each `CamPosLookArray.PosLookArray` within the `Camera_Positioning.PosLook` array.

Comment: MotoSV, can I mail you some beer?  Because this is now the third time you have come to my rescue lol <3.

Comment: Moto was there anything else you changed?  Because I am not getting the same thing you have in that picture

Answer (score 2):

You could try to have a script that has an array of Camera_Positioning.

EDIT:

```
public class Test: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera_Container [] camPos;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Camera_Container{
    public Camera_Positioning [] camPos;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Camera_Positioning
{
    public Transform cameraPosition;
    public Transform cameraLook;
    public int story;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it made a drag and drop to put that script in.  Would I have to make an Editor script for this new script that has an array of Camera_Positioning as well?

Comment: See the dit, I have a class that contains an array of the Camera_Positioning. Then that class gets to be an array within a component. The layout is different to yours as I think you use some editor script.